# Python3 Date Validation

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I validate this date time in python 3 - `2018-05-30-16-54-00` ?

When I pass this date text to below method , an error is returned.

```
def validate(date_text):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M-%S')
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MI-SS")
```

Comment: You mean your `ValueError` is raised?

Comment: Cannot replicate your issue. You ask Python to raise an error when unsuccessful, and this is the error you get.

Comment: Yes , my ValueError is raised. got it to work after I used Patrick's solution

Comment: You’re explicitly asking it to validate times in DD-MMM-YYYY format when you want YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Also, it’s worth noting that even if you get this right, it isn’t validating what you think it is, because `strptime` is lenient—e.g., if you pass it a single-digit month, it will parse it correctly instead of complaining. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Oh ok , no that is not. Should I use a different function then ?

Comment: @abarnert has a good point here. Changed answer to include a regex parsing step to mitigate that problem.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert and Patrick Artner. This helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix the datetime string - it must match exactly. Read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

```
"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"
```

Your string `'%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M-%S'` is parsing day, month name abreviated (locale aware), year, H-M-S.

If you need to validate to 0 before the months/days etc, combine your parsing with a regex check:

```
import re
import datetime

def validate(date_text):
    """Validates the overall structure with regex and parses the datetime using 
    strptime to test for "existing" months and times. """
    try:
        dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
        if re.match(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}", date_text) is None:
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MI-SS")    

v = ["2018-06-01-10-20-30", "2018-6-01-10-20-30", "2018-21-01-10-20-30"]
for k in v:
    try:
        print("Validating: ", k)
        validate(k)
        print("ok")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Output:

```
Validating:  2018-06-01-10-20-30
ok
Validating:  2018-6-01-10-20-30       # missing 0
Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MI-SS
Validating:  2018-21-01-10-20-30      # no 21 month possible
Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MI-SS
```

Comment: Thanks , it works! just saw the documentation as well.